# iphone offline application runs fine from safari but not from desktop

Tags: iphone, html, safari, offline-caching, cache-manifest

I made a webapp that uses a manifest file to work offline.

The files are "text/cache-manifest" (*due to a .htaccess file, HTML5 Boiler Plate*) and in the console of Google Chrome I check all files are loaded properly.

When i test my application without Internet in a PC or an ipad (iOS5) (both Safari and desktop icon) all works fine. When I start my application on a iphone (iOS 6) from Safari web browser without internet all seems to work fine, **but when you start the webapp clicking on desktop I recieved the message I can't open the application without Internet.**

I tried with the names "cache.manifest" and "manifest.appcache" for the manifest file.

Anyone can point me to the right direction? Thanks!